# Modify name of Opportunity during Lead Conversion

Tags: conversion

Par défaut lors de la conversion d'une piste, l'opportunité est renommée avec le nom du compte. Où dois je aller pour modifier ce paramètre et définir que ce soit le prénom et le nom du contact ?
Je n'ai rien trouver dans les paramètres de mappage des champs dans l'enregistrement piste.
Merci de vos retours

> By default when converting a lead, the opportunity is renamed with the account name. Where should I go to modify this parameter and define that it is the first and last name of the contact? I couldn't find anything in the field mapping settings in the track record. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  This is an English-only site; I used Google Translate to convert your French.  To chnage the Opportunity Name; you'll need to do that in Flow or Trigger that executes when the Opportunity is created via lead conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Lead convert setting to adjust the Opportunity Name to some different pattern

What you can do is the following:

- Create a custom formula checkbox field on Lead called `Is_Lead__c`, default true. Don't show on the page layout
- Create a custom Opportunity checkbox field called `Is_Created_From_Lead_Conversion__c`. Make it read only on the page layout
- Create a Lead mapping rule that aps `Lead.Is_Lead__c` to `Opportunity_Is_Created_From_Lead_Conversion__c`
- Use a Before Create Flow or Before insert trigger to:

  - Change the Opportunity.Name to the name you need but only if `Opportunity_Is_Created_From_Lead_Conversion__c = true`

Comment: Merci pour votre retour, je m'attendais à quelque chose de plus simple mais c'est parfait.

Comment: Sorry I don't have something simpler - if the answer works for you, as a service to the Community, please mark it as accepted so others will know that the solution works

Comment: Merci mais je n'ai pas les compétences pour mettre en œuvre ces solutions.